# Android App prevent from being modified

Tags: java, android, admob

After Googling I have found that my free app with ads is published in some sites with title "app_name_ad_free_mod_hacked", after trying to install this app in my personal phone it is working correctly but ads aren't showing. Even, I noticed that it doesn't make ad request.

Is there any solution to prevent the app from being modified?

P.S: I'm using ProGuard and I have decompiled the modified APK, and I don't notice any difference from original app.

Ads are initialized in my code as below :

At `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` :

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "admob_app_id");
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView_fragment_ads);
layout_ads = findViewById(R.id.layout_fragments_ads);
start_ad();
```

and the method :

```
private void start_ad() {
        try {
            if (data_ne_db[0].equals("jo")) {
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                        .addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.ads_test_device))
                        .addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.ads_test_device_facebook))
                        .build();
                //mAdView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ads_kryesorja_poshte));
                //mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.LARGE_BANNER);
                mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest);
                mAdView1.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        mAdView1.resume();
                        mAdView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        u_inicializua = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        Log.e("ADDD CLOSEEEED", "Ads is closed by user)");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        mAdView1.pause();
                        Log.e("AD FRAG 2", "Ads failed to load" + " error : " + errorCode);
                        u_inicializua = false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdOpened() {
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
```

Maybe someone just injects comment to the method call or in the database if check, but how to prevent that?

Comment: People can download an apk and "open it" doing reverse engineering. An apk is like a zip file that contains the sources (try for example to rename example.apk to example.zip and you'll see what happens). You can obfuscate the code, use proguard and everything but there would be very frequently a way to get the source code

Comment: I have decompiled the modified apk, and i don't notice any difference from original app, i know there is a difference but i can't find it

Comment: keep everything in the server.... and the app just displays views. think of app that use user details.... facebook for example. nothing is on the local....more than likely they have an API key. Similar to firebase/parse. hwever, for parse, you can write cloud code (which is now on a server) however, if the user doesnt have a masterkey, they cant run the APIs since the methods in the server require the master key.

Comment: My app, should stay local, i just want to secure ads, nothing else. So i mean, peoples can do everything they want, but just not to disable ads.

Comment: nothing will make that STOP. however, the majority of people who use applications dont know how to, or have the resources /tech background to do it.

Comment: I know that it can't be stopped but maybe something to make it really harder... I don't know what to do, maybe many checks, runtime checks....

Comment: @DroiDev
`the majority of people who use applications dont know how to, or have the resources /tech background to do it`

haha, there is crackers and Google for them. I think, if google gets strict about this issue, something really can be done, I mean something can be done to make vampires and pirates some mad. Maybe not 100% but, 60% atleast. :-( :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making hacking impossible: I don't know if there is an answer.

What you can do is: There are some paid tools like [dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard). You can use them. A paid alternative will likely work better than a free one.

Though, an expert one might get into your code. But, cracking [dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard) isn't a simple game.
Also, it does Runtime Self Protection, Code optimization, etc

---

Some of my unused ideas::-P | Client Side

- Check the location from where the application was installed. Use **PackageManager**
- Verify Signature of the application installed / Place Signature in the server | Check if matches the one with which the app is signed
- Make code which even you can't read after a day of finishing it. **Badly** name classes, **wrongly** name them. Like: Class *ABACAS* processes task *ABACAS* and class *SACABA* does task *SACABA* - give them reversed name. Also, method *delegate* returns some value called *delegate* and method *stack* returns *stack*. Reversely name them.

> That means: Class *ABACAS* will do *SACABA* and *SACABA* will do
>   *ABACAS* & method *delegate* will return *stack* and method *stack* will return *delegate*

---

If your app is server-dependent (I mean your app is just is a client, the server does the task, has API and does send-receive). Just ask your app for the signature from the server. If the signatures match does next, else return.

Comment: What if someone still modified the app but still sends mocked apk signature while connecting with the server?

Comment: @AkshayShinde How are you supposed to mock the signature? Actually, I'm talking about how firebase app signature verification work.